# How to show topics of reuters dataset in Keras?

Tags: deep-learning, keras, text-classification

I use reuters dataset in Keras.

And I want to know the 46 topics' names.

How can I show topics of reuters dataset in Keras?

https://keras.io/datasets/#reuters-newswire-topics-classification

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Associated mapping of topic labels as per original [Reuters Dataset](https://martin-thoma.com/nlp-reuters/) with the topic indexes in Keras version is:

```
['cocoa','grain','veg-oil','earn','acq','wheat','copper','housing','money-supply',
 'coffee','sugar','trade','reserves','ship','cotton','carcass','crude','nat-gas',
 'cpi','money-fx','interest','gnp','meal-feed','alum','oilseed','gold','tin',
 'strategic-metal','livestock','retail','ipi','iron-steel','rubber','heat','jobs',
 'lei','bop','zinc','orange','pet-chem','dlr','gas','silver','wpi','hog','lead']
```

To understand the approach of extracting the above mapping, please follow [this thread comment](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/12072#issuecomment-458154097).